# Website doesn't allow right click and web scrape does not show text between body tags

Tags: python, html, selenium, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to web scrape a web page. However, the website itself does not allow a right click functionality to inspect the element or page source. In addition, when I print the parsed html text, the result only has body tags and does not show the information inside the body tags.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'PATH')
driver.get("website.com")

assert "Title" in driver.title

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('website.com').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I expect to get the actual HTML (specifically HTML between the body tags) from the soup; however, I only get

```
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>Title</title>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I am relatively new to webscraping; however, I never had this problem before. Is it specific to the site? When I use a chrome extension, I am able to allow for right clicking, and only then, can I inspect the page source (and there is HTML and tags within the body tags).

Comment: That problem sounds very site-specific, as I have never encountered anything like it before. It looks like you are getting the page HTML through BeautifulSoup correctly too, and it's returning something so your command definitely executed correctly. My only suggestion for you is to try `F12` to open the page source instead of right click. Could you provide the site URL you are trying to access? If it's public, we may be able to take a look.

Comment: `F12` does allow for inspection; however, is there a way around retrieving the HTML body tag information?

Comment: Does the inspection show any information inside <body> or is it empty as well? I did post a small solution to use Selenium to get the page source. We can compare and see if it's the same or different than what you get through BeautifulSoup.

Comment: http://menu.dartmouth.edu/

Comment: It looks like BS stripped out the script tags, which is super-annoying. I always try to use a proper HTML5 parser.

Comment: The webpage's HTML does not have any body content (`CTRL+U` on the webpage to view source in browser). Inspection tools show the content after it was loaded by JavaScript. In your code sample, the HTML retrieved by `urllib` will have no body content. Since they have an AJAX API, just use that instead (`F12` -> `Network` tab). You can retrieve the menus with `"get_webmenu_list"`, meals with `"get_webmenu_meals_list"`, recipes with `"get_recipes_for_menumealdate"`, etc.

Comment: @SébastienVercammen, I see how the content loads after, by the JavaScript. How did you find `"get_webmenu_list"`, `"get_webmenu_meals_list"`, etc. and how would I access them in my python script?

Comment: I think the Requests library for Python is a good tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the body tag information using just Python / Selenium and see if the page source is any different than what you posted in your question. This will help narrow down the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("website.com")

html = driver.page_source

print(html)
```

If this produces the same results as HTML you posted in your question, then the issue is probably with the website itself and not your code.

Comment: It shows more of the page source; however, it does not show all of it.

Comment: It displays some div tags in the body tag; however, it does not show all of them.

Comment: driver.page_source should be the entire page source. Are all the tags closed at the end of or does it look like the text may have been cut off?

Comment: I believe page_source has an issue where it's only valid for after page load, so other  dynamically loaded data won't appear with it. I think this site is doing some sneaky/tricky stuff that will need a special technique.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer the question but it should get your context menu back:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  window.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }, true)
""")
```